# What happened to Muslim spouses who converted to Christianity during the 1923 Graeco-Turkish population exchange?

Tags: political-history, turkey, greece, population-transfer

[The Greek - Turkish Population Exchange Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_exchange_between_Greece_and_Turkey) was signed on 30 January 1923. The population exchange was based on religious identity - involving denaturalization of the Orthodox Christian population of Turkey and the Muslim population of Greece.

My question is about the situation of the Muslim population on the Greek side. What was the legal situation of the converts, who wanted to stay in Greece, and converted to Christianity after the convention date?
More specifically, what happened to Turkish women married to Greek men after the convention date, and decided to stay in Greece as a Greek.

We know that in both sides, many people changed religions to stay.
On the Turkish side, at least on the official side, the Orthodox Greek women marrying to Turkish men were only allowed to stay in Turkey, if the marriage was prior to the convention date. It was even subject to a government decree dated 27 July 1924 in the Turkish side, to clarify such situation, which did not allow post convention marriages.

I want to understand the similar situation in Greece, with regards to Muslim women marrying Greek men, after the convention date. Were they allowed to stay, or was there the same situation as in Turkey, where only the pre-convention married women were allowed to stay?

Answer (score 6):

Officially, If you were a Muslim in Greece, you could be exempt from compulsory deportation if you were:

- part of the ethnic Albanian community
- a resident of Thrace

The Greek government had placed no restrictions on religious conversions via marriage or baptism in the same fashion that the Turkish government did. Last minute conversions to prevent deportation were allowed and this applied to both men and women. It is unclear if there were specific rules for women

Here is an example of marriages occurring in Crete in order to prevent evacuation:

> ...findings reveal that some male members of Muslim families in Crete avoided the population exchange either by way of converting to Christianity or getting married to the local Greek women. Thereby, it became possible to prevent the properties of their families from confiscation. See Raif Kaplanoglu, Bursa'da Miibadele (1923-1930 Yunanistan Gogmenleri) (Bursa: Avrasya Etnografya Vakfi Yaylnlarl, 1999)

**- Diplomacy and Displacement: Reconsidering the Turco-Greek Exchange of populations, 1922-1934 (Onur Yildirim, pg 249)**

If your identification papers read that you where Orthodox and not Muslim, you where exempt from the population exchange.

Furthermore, marriage in the Orthodox church requires that both husband and wife must profess the Christian faith. Therefore those Muslim men and women who married into Orthodox families had to convert as a pre-requisite to their marriage.

Comment: OP asks about women; most of  your answer focuses on men. Is that because there is very little documentation on women?

Comment: There is very little documentation in English about the situation of women. There probably exists Turkish accounts of individuals marrying to avoid deportation. unfortunately i dont know Turkish and the best info i could find in English is on males. Will edit accordingly

Comment: Kapetanios, I am checking Diplomacy and Displacement in detail. It is true that there had been lot's of conversions in both sides to prevent forced immigration. However, I cannot find sources documenting that such conversions were allowed after Lousanne Agreement. During Lousanne negotiations, many people converted. It was so fast in the Turkish side that the Turkish government at some time froze the official registry of marriages. However, later on passed a decree to allow all conversions and marriages pre-Convention. This also included many post Convention conversions, back date registered

Comment: What I am trying to understand is whether or not such conversions were allowed in the Greek side, if the official (registered on state) conversion date was after the Lausanne Convention.

Comment: @Can As i mentioned in the answer "The Greek government had placed no restrictions on religious conversions via marriage or baptism in the same fashion that the Turkish government did". Exactly who could be baptised was solely determined by the Orthodox church and not the state. And there is no documented cases of Orthodox priests or bishops refusing to baptise Muslims prior to or after the Lausanne agreement.

Comment: Hi Kapetanios. Your answers have been very helpful. I am also reading all the references you put. Still, I am mainly looking for a evidence or reference for the allowance of post-convention marriage or conversion.

Comment: In the Turkish side, conversion was not prevented (as conversion is only a personal decision, and is not subject to any religious or official authority's approval) Also, the women marrying muslim men do not need to change religion. But the government refused to delete such people from the list of exchangees, marrying or converted after the convention date. (They were thinking of mass numbers of fake conversions) So it may be the case in the Greek side that the Orthodox Church accepted people, but state still refused to delete them off the lists. In any case, I am just looking for a reference.

Comment: Twice a Stranger by Bruce Clark states: "Pandelis Prevelakis, a Cretan novelist who witnessed the Muslim exodus at the age of fourteen, said news of the population exchange came as a terrible shock to both the island's communities. They were 'like a couple whose divorce is pronounced at the very moment when they have buried the hatchet'. At least 1000 Cretan Muslims asked if they could make last-minute reconversions to Christianity, but the Archbishop of Athens refused this request." As a result, it was not totally allowed everywhere.

Comment: good find @Can. As you can see, finding information on this is not so easy. You need to resort to personal accounts from the time it occured. To that end, you'll find that these issues where dealt with on a case-by-case basis. I suspect that the Archbishop of Athens at the time (if the source is true) refused the request because baptism for the purposes of convenience rather than genuine acceptance of the faith was deemed unacceptable.

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised that the Archbishop of Athens was appealed to by Cretan Muslims, rather than the Archbishop of Crete or the Patriarch (Crete does not belong to the Church of Greece, so the Archbishop of Athens had no ecclesiastical jurisdiction there). But I guess with Crete recently annexed to Greece, and the political decision was implemented by the Greek government, they felt they had to take the issue up with Athens.